Dockerfile parse error on line 5: ADD requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   3 |     RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat
   4 |     WORKDIR /opt/tomcat
   5 | >>> ADD https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.28/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.28.tar.gz
   6 |     RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-10.1.28.tar.gz
   7 |     RUN mv apache-tomcat-10.1.28/* /opt/tomcat
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: dockerfile parse error on line 5: ADD requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined

Created a dockerfile as above and ran build to create docker image and it returned with the above error. Below are the contents of my dockerfile:
FROM centos:latest 
RUN yum install java -y 
RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat 
WORKDIR /opt/tomcat 
ADD https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.28/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.28.tar.gz 
RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-10.1.28.tar.gz 
RUN mv apache-tomcat-10.1.28/* /opt/tomcat 
EXPOSE 8080 
CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]


ADD takes two parameters, just as the error message says. You probably want just ., the current directory, as the destination, given the following lines.
ADD https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.28/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.28.tar.gz .
                                                                           Add this----^^^ 

